# How to use globally installed Composer packages in multiple projects?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a ever growing list of Composer packages that are required by multiple projects on my local system. Is there a configuration setting and/or hack to get Composer to look for a package in the current directory and fallback to the global directory if not found.

I know there is `[config][use-include-path]` setting but I'm guessing that's not performant.

I know Composer is only meant for [single-project dependency management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671416/using-composer-can-dependencies-be-shared-between-multiple-projects) but in this case I reinstalling the same packages (at the same version) over and over again.

Comment: Solution here: [GitHub](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/55)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you mentioned, Composer is meant only for single-project dependency management. 
You will (at some point) run into incompatibilities when you update a package globally. While one project needs the update, another project is getting incompatible because a local package of this project needs the older version.

Do you (and any other developer working with you) a favor and use it as single-project dependency. If you need to update the same packages again and again write a script or something which updates the whole bunch of projects at once if you like. But hell keep your composer clean.

Btw [Composer caches your packages](http://moquet.net/blog/5-features-about-composer-php/#4.-prefer-dist-packages-and-cache-them) when you install from `dist`. So only the first install downloads from the Internet, the rest is installed from cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a git repository somewhere and then just clone that to bootstrap your new projects.